# Number of eigenvalues and dimension of Image space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I was trying to prove something related to the eigenvalues and the truth is that I don't even know how to start.

If $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation such that $\dim (\text{Im}(T))=7$. Then $T$ has at most 8 eigenvalues.

I don't see what relation exists between the number of eigenvalues and the dimension of the image space. I'd appreciate if someone can give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the following: eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are linearly independent. More precisely, the following statement holds.

> Assume that $v_1, \dots, v_k \in V$ are eigenvectors, with $Tv_i=\lambda_i v_i$, and $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ if $i\neq j$. Then $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are linearly independent.

In fact, assume that they are linearly independent. We may assume (up to dropping some of them) that the collection is minimal with this property, i.e. $v_1, \dots, \hat{v}_i, \dots, v_k$ is linearly independent for all $i$. Fix some linear relation $a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k=0$, where not all $a_i$ are zero.

Note that $a_i\neq 0$, as otherwise $v_1, \dots, \hat{v}_i, \dots, v_k$ will be linearly dependent. Apply now $T$ to the equality, which yields
$$ 0 = T(a_1v_1)+\dots + T(a_kv_k) = a_1\lambda_1v_1+\dots+a_k\lambda_kv_k. $$
Now, we have that
$$ \begin{align*} 0 &= a_1\lambda_1v_1+\dots+a_k\lambda_kv_k - \lambda_1(a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k) \\ &= (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)a_2v_2+\dots+(\lambda_k-\lambda_1)a_kv_k. \end{align*} $$
Note that the coefficients are non-zero, and so $v_2, \dots, v_k$ are linearly dependent, a contradiction.

Keeping this in mind, is fairly easy to see what happens: if $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are eigenvectors for different eigenvalues, then $Tv_1=\lambda_1v_1, \dots, Tv_k=\lambda_kv_k$ are linearly independent, unless some $\lambda_i$ is zero. Therefore, if there are $s$ different eigenvalues, the image contains at least $s-1$ linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely understood your explanation.